# Get the primary key column from dbSet

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbset

I want to write a function, which receives any `Entity` object and finds the current value by automatically determined primary key and updates it.

Could you please point me any direction.

```
 public void Update(object entity)
 {
     using (var _db = new MyEntities())
     {
        var table  = _db.Set(entity.GetType());
//Here we should somehow find the entity object which primary key coincides with the one of entity
        var entityObj = table.FindObjectByPrimaryKey(entity);
        entityObj.CopyDataFrom(entity);
        _db.SaveChanges()

     }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

you can find primary keys of an entity like this

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_db).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<YourEntity> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<YourEntity>();
IEnumerable<string> keyNames = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                            .KeyMembers
                                            .Select(k => k.Name);
```

and then use reflection to access their values.

Comment: I don't have the `YourEnity` class here. What can I do is dynamically get the type of the entity instance: `entity.GetType()`.

Comment: @Vahagn You should make your method generic to begin with.

Comment: Adding on doctor's solution, according to https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/find-primary-keys-from-entities-from-dbcontext/#comment-156, there are improvements to be made (such as performance) to this approach.

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer.

```
 public void Update(object entity)
 {   
     using (var _db = new MyEntities())
     {           
        _db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;             
        _db.SaveChanges();

     }
 }
```

Comment: is this really "Get the primary key column from dbSet in C#"??